# Does "They themselves" need commas?

Tags: commas

Which of the following sentences has correct comma usage?

> a) They themselves can state their feelings.
>
> b) They themselves, can state their feelings.
>
> c) They, themselves, can state their feelings.

Comment: Regardless of which one has correct comma usage, there is no need for the reflexive in that sentence. It reads like this sentence was taken from one of Bush's speeches- never a good sign.

Comment: @ParthianShot, this isn't a reflexive pronoun: it's an intensive one.

Comment: @Anonym You're half right; it's both. Still, putting the intensive pronoun right next to the noun it's intesifying has always bugged me. I want that usage to die out. And if the comments section is not my venue to dispense [soapbox judgment on how English ought to be used](https://xkcd.com/1483/), then what, really, is it for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following option poses no confusion in my mind, and I wouldn't anticipate confusion in the mind of a native speaker:

> a) They themselves can state their feelings.

The supporting data of the *[corpus](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22they%20themselves%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)* suggests that the expression *they themselves* is not usually separated by a comma, and since it is the subject of the verbal phrase *can state*, it should not be separated from the predicate with a comma.

*Themselves* is a *[reflexive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_pronoun)*, and in the phrase *they themselves*, it is an intensive form, which is always treated as a *[restrictive appositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition#Restrictive_versus_non-restrictive)* that is not offset with a comma.

> Note that they all have reflexive and intensive forms which depends on
> where they are in the sentence.
>
> *Jim bought **himself** a book* (reflexive)
> *Jim **himself** bought a book* (intensive)
> *Asjad brought **himself** a book* (reflexive)
> *Asjad **himself** brought a book* (intensive)
>
> Intensive pronouns usually appear right near the subject of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just get rid of "themselves," and the problem is solved.
Otherwise, b is definitely wrong, and c doesn't feel right either, so I'd go with a.